# How do you call upon a javascript saved in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, html, rel

I'm building a simple game with 100 html pages and as you navigate through the pages a randomly selected piece of the story appears on the page. So far the game is working perfectly, but I would like to modify it so that I can have the javascript array that contains the story to be in a single file each html page can call upon, so I can edit the story once and not update 100 pages every time I add to it.

Originally my javascript was on each page inside of the "display" div hard-coded.

Edit: I edited my code as per the instructions, and it's still not showing up.

heres my html page:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="story.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
</div>


<div class="display_wrapper">
<div class="left_display">
</div>

<div class="display">



</div>

<div class="right_display">
</div>
</div>



<div class="left_nav">
</div>

<div class="nav">
<center>

<input type="button" id="north" value="north" onclick="window.location.href =  +Math.floor(Math.random() 

* 101) +'.html';" /> <br />

<input type="button" id="west" value="west" onclick="window.location.href =  +Math.floor(Math.random() * 

101) +'.html';" />  
<input type="button" id="east" value="east" onclick="window.location.href =  +Math.floor(Math.random() * 

101) +'.html';" /> <br />

<input type="button" id="south" value="south" onclick="window.location.href =  +Math.floor(Math.random() 

* 101) +'.html';" /> 
</center>
</div>
<div class="right_nav">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's my javascript I'm calling for:

```
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "Nothings here, you should keep moving before something shows up though.";
r_text[1] = "Nothings here, you should keep moving before something shows up though.";
r_text[2] = "Nothings here, you should keep moving before something shows up though.";
r_text[3] = "You found a piece of crumbled paper on the ground. It stood out on the ground because of the 

sharp contrast between the white of the paper and the red of the blood staining it. Desperate for any 

clues leading out of this eerie town, you pick it up and smooth it out carefully as to not damage it 

further. It reads as follows: 888 paces north, 636 paces east, 770 paces west, 946 paces west.. no end in 

sight..";
r_text[4] = "You can't see anything, you don't hear anything, but a chill just shot down your spine and you 

cant shake this deep feeling of uneasiness.";
r_text[5] = "A strange smell like that of a rotting corpse hits your nose. You should turn back.";
r_text[6] = "You look and look and even shout out if anyone can hear you and find nothing, but you cant 

shake the feeling that you're being watched.";
r_text[7] = "You look and look and even shout out if anyone can hear you and find nothing, but you cant 

shake the feeling that you're being watched.";
r_text[8] = "You walk down a street of decrep old buildings that all seem uninhabited. No one is around, 

not even stray animals. For as far as you can see in every direction is nothing but more old ruined 

buildings.";
r_text[9] = "You walk down a street of decrep old buildings that all seem uninhabited. No one is around, 

not even stray animals. For as far as you can see in every direction is nothing but more old ruined 

buildings.";
r_text[10] = "You walk down a street of decrep old buildings that all seem uninhabited. No one is around, 

not even stray animals. For as far as you can see in every direction is nothing but more old ruined 

buildings.";
r_text[11] = "You happen upon a building with an open doorway. The building looks stable enough to 

explore so you walk up to the entrance. Near the doorway, you find an old dusty sign with writing you cant 

quite read on it. After dusting the sign-off, you find out this build used to be the town's library. You 

enter optimistically thinking you'll find some clues on how to leave the acursed town, or what happened 

to the inhabitants. <p>Carefully you explore the internal perimeter of the library to make sure there's 

nothing inside waiting for you. Upon securing that there are no other living things in the library beside 

yourself, you switch to your next goal: finding information. Searching for hours and hours through 

hundreds of books taken randomly from just about every shelf you skim the contents of every book looking 

for some scrap of useful information. From what you can gather the town's name is Innsmouth and it used 

to be a thriving fishery and gold refinery but war and inbreeding dwindled the town's population to 

nearly nothing. <p>Esoteric cults moved into the desolate town with promise of economic recovery through 

prayer and converted most of the surviving population, though rumors were the conversions were mostly by 

force. Articles of disappearances were the only other useful bits of information that could be called 

recent but the last one was dated fifteen years ago. You slump down in your chair, sigh a great sigh, 

then stretch your legs and stand up to go find the nearest window. It's almost dark. You decide to spend 

the night in the library. During your final inspection of the place before going to sleep for anything 

lurking, you find a book that seemed wholly out of place, it looked like an ancient tome, extradanarily 

thick and fantastically decorated. The very look of it was sinister. <p>For a minute you debated whether 

you should look through it, toss it out of the building or find a whole other building to sleep in for 

the night. Ultimately you decide you came here for useful information and this is the only book in the 

a whole library that looks promising. Without picking it up, you stand near enough to read the title.. The 

Necronomicon. Hesitantly, you pick the book up as if it were a venomous snake ready to strike at any 

moment. Carefully you lay it on a nearby table and proceed to open the front cover.<p> You spend the 

entire night pouring over the ancient time until the light of day stings your over-strained dry eyes. The 

the only way to maintain your own sanity after reading the contents of The Necronomicon you resign yourself 

believe this was the Bible to the esoteric cults who took over Innsmouth and it is nothing more than 

religious fanatic gobbilty-gook. The world in which you and every other person on this earth and the 

world portrayed in The Necronomicon just CANT be the same one. You try and try to get some sleep but 

every time you close your eyes one of the frightful monsters depicted in the Necronomicon came to the 

front of your mind's eye. You decide it would be best to put away the tome and not touch it again, and 

focus on resting up so you may try venturing out tomorrow morning to find a way out of this increasingly 

frightening town.";
r_text[12] = "You feel like you've been walking for hours without finding anything useful, any people, 

animals, or ways out of the town.";
r_text[13] = "you find an abandoned general store, through the windows it looks like there may be some 

rations still inside. You try for the door but its baracaded by some fallen roof beams. After surveying 

the area for anything lurking and confirming that you are alone within normal earshot, you take a large 

a chunk of fallen brick and break open an entrance through a large front window. The sound of the glass 

breaking was the first sound you've heard in uncountable hours. Your heart pounds and you're sure SOMETHING 

lurking out there heard you and must be coming after you now. You're first instinct is to hide. <p>You 

hide behind a counter and scope out your surroundings fervently listening for the slightest little sound. 

The sound of your own heart pounding makes it hard to hear anything else. Every time you think it's ok to 

move, you realize your frightened state of mind can make five minutes feel like hours, again and again 

you stop yourself from moving. Hours pass by and you notice a distinct change in the sun's position from 

the shadows sprawled out on the floor. Finally, you decide its safe to venture out in search of rations 

after one more survey of the inside of the store. Your efforts paid off in enough water to satisfy your 

thirst and some old canned goods easily opened with tools also found in the shop you gladly chanced and 

wolfed down. You decide to hold up in this store until you're fully recovered and resolved to venture out 

in the town again to find a way out.";
r_text[14] = "while trying to find a suitable shelter for the soon-coming night, you walk up to a 

building with an open doorway and peer inside. instantly a chill creeps down your spine. a glimpse of a 

dusty sign catches your gaze and you quickly dust it off to read it. It reads: The Esoteric Order of 

Dagon. This is one of the churches of the cult that took over the town and quite possibly caused the 

town's mass dissertion.<p> After that terrifying realization gave way to the ability to control your 

limbs again, you decide to run and find a different shelter as far away from this building as you can. ";
r_text[15] = "while walking around the town you notice most of the land appears to be flat and the 

numerous old delatidated buildings made it very hard to see much more than a few hundred feet down a 

single street at a time. All of a sudden you spot the first elevation you've to see since you've arrived. You 

race for it to try and gain a vantage point of any kind to figure out which direction to go. The 

elevation turns out to be less than 10 feet high and gives almost no vantage point as your view is still 

obstructed by all of the ancient tottering buildings. You need need to climb on top of a roof to gain any 

vantage. ";
r_text[16] = "during your time exploring the town you have noticed most of the roads have been unmarked 

or had their street signs torn down with no remnant of the name left to be read. That fact is what made 

this street before you stand out from all the other identical streets you've been walking up and down 

endlessly. An intact street sign that read the Main street. What luck! It doesn't matter which direction you 

follow the street, Main should always lead to other streets that will allow you to LEAVE the town! <p>You 

follow the Main street for as far as your legs can take you day in and day out, only stopping during the 

night to take shelter in nearby abandoned buildings, and looking for food and water. Weeks passed by and 

still, not a single change in the scenery could be found, no people, no animals, everything in bitter 

unyielding silence. There seems to be no foreseeable end to this street.";
r_text[17] = "the sun is high in the sky and heading toward dusk. it happens much quicker than it should 

and light becomes scarce in this town with no electricity after the sun starts to come back down. This is 

about the time I start looking for a shelter to stay the night in, preferably something with drinkable 

water inside as the search for food was given up long ago. After trying three other houses on this street 

I find one with a door I can pry open. Upon entering the house I'm overcome with the stench of mold and 

mildew, which means there must be water somewhere. I decide to investigate. <p>Very silently I roam around 

the house with nothing but a few sunspots to light my way. It's almost impossible to distinguish what 

each room's original purpose was, there was no discernable kitchen or bathroom to be made out in such 

little light without blindly groping in the dark to maybe find something that resembles a sink, toilet, 

tub or exposed pipes, which was not something I was quite ignorant enough to do. Upon entering the next 

room I hear something squish under my foot and feel a dampness. After walking a few more steps I discover 

the entire floor is covered in less than an inch of water. I would imagine its rainwater leaked through 

the same holes in the walls and roof the sunspots are coming from, however, I've been in this town for a 

while now and I've not once seen it rain. <p>I kneel down and cup my hands to scoop up some water. First I 

feel the texture, is it slimy, sludgy, or sooty? Next, I smell it, is it tainted or fresh rainwater? It 

felt stagnant, not dirty but not necessarily fresh. It had been here a while for certain. The smell was 

what threw me for a loop, it was distinctively salty, like ocean water. <p> Nonetheless, I couldn't drink 

it. 
I was, however, curious as to how salty ocean water got into this house. But the quickly fading sunlight 

was not enough to give a thorough investigation. On my way toward what I thought was the exit, I found a 

staircase leading up I had not found earlier. The light seemed the be stronger upstairs, so I thought a 

few minutes of sunlight would be worth a vantage point of the town from a second-story window, and maybe 

perhaps an easy-enough climb to a roof. <p>The stairs seemed sturdy enough but they creaked rather loudly 

under my feet. I unconsciously held my breath as I walked up the stairs and exhaled when I could actually 

see the second floor of the house, it wasn't brightly lit by any means but enough sun poured in from old 

windows and holes in the roof to light the second floor well enough for it to be easily explored. The 

smell of mildrew was stronger up here as well and I soon found the bottom of my shoes to be soaked. 

Everything up here was wet like a firehose had been taken to it. I instinctively head toward the most 

brightly lit room, hoping for an open window. Peering in the doorway I find my open window! 

<p>Unfortunately, the room is flooded with several inches of water and broken household objects litterly 

the floor, poking up from the water like bones from a hastily-dug grave. I decided to check the other 

rooms first. The second room I try has a closed door and it won't budge, it seems to be baracaded from the 

other side. The next room is open but there's a large hole in the middle of the floor and it doesn't seem 

to be stable enough to walk across to get to the nearest window. The first room is the best option. 

-------------------------------------- ";
r_text[18] = "Nestled down in my shelter for the night, having made sure all was quiet and vacant before 

attempting to fall asleep. Abruptly, in the dead of the night, I'm awakened by the croaking of frogs 

outside. Up until this very moment I hadn't heard or seen so much as a living insect, let alone a frog. 

This disturbed me greatly.";
r_text[19] = "saw a fishfrog creature";
r_text[20] = "saw a cultist group";
r_text[21] = "saw cthulhu";
r_text[22] = "hear noises";
r_text[23] = "chased by a cultist";
r_text[24] = "find cultist materials";
r_text[25] = "spot cultists or fishfrogs on devils reef";
r_text[26] = "chased by fishfrogs";
r_text[27] = "found an underground tunnel";
r_text[28] = "cthulhu dreams";
r_text[29] = "I hear strange spectral piping";
r_text[30] = "when i saw the people, or what i thought were people, i instantly shouted out to them to 

get their attention. i wish i hadnt done that.";
r_text[31] = "a night of despair";
r_text[32] = "i thought it was a dream but it wasnt, how did I get here?";
r_text[33] = "going inside a church to investigate";
r_text[34] = "event 34";
r_text[35] = "event 35";    
r_text[36] = "event 36";
r_text[37] = "event 37";
r_text[38] = "event 38";
r_text[39] = "event 39";
r_text[40] = "event 40";
r_text[41] = "event 41";
r_text[42] = "event 42";
r_text[43] = "event 43";
r_text[44] = "event 44";
r_text[45] = "event 45";
r_text[46] = "event 46";
r_text[47] = "event 47";
r_text[48] = "event 48";
r_text[49] = "event 49";
r_text[50] = "event 50";

var i = Math.floor(51*Math.random())
document.getElementsByClassName("display")[0].append( r_text[i] );
```

Comment: By the way, I would highly recommend against having 100 separate HTML files you have to maintain. Instead of having the user click links to new pages, you could have them click buttons that call JavaScript that changes the page. This would allow you to just have 1 HTML file to maintain instead of dozens.

Comment: I edited the code as everyone said but still nothing is showing up inside the "display" div

Comment: Also, I hadnt really thought of that. Everything is already set up, would changing my code for the buttons to trigger the dialogue to show up rather than go to a page be any more difficult than figuring out my problem Im having now? Because if I did that I can leave my dialogues hard-coded into the same page which already worked.  I guess I could accept either answer if its simple enough. Ill be kicking myself later though for editing 100 pages a few times over though lol

Comment: You don't have any code that writes to the display div. Your web browser doesn't care where your script tag is; that makes no difference in how the JS is executed. Merely calling `document.write()` will just add your text to the end of the document. You'll want to do `document.getElementsByClassName("display")[0].append( r_text[i] );`

Comment: I just tried that and it didnt work either. =/

Answer (score 1):

Link tags aren't used for JavaScript. You want this tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="whateverYourFileIsCalled.js"></script>
```

Your JS file shouldnt have any script tags in it; it should just be JavaScript without any HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the link tag with a script tag:

```
 <script src="story.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `<script>` tags inside a JavaScript file. `<script>` tags are for HTML only.

Also, you include JS inside HTML not with `<rel>` but with `<script>`, namely with

```
<script src="story.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<link>` tags aren't used for Javascript, so get rid of that line.  The `<script>` tag inside your "display" `div` will do the job.

Next, remove the `<script>` tags in the `story.js` file (it's Javascript, not HTML).

The contents of that file should be just:

```
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "Nothings here, you should keep moving before something shows up though.";
r_text[1] = "Nothings here, you should keep moving before something shows up though.";
r_text[2] = "Nothings here, you should keep moving before something shows up though.";
r_text[3] = "You found a piece of crumbled paper on the ground. It stood out on the ground because of the 

sharp contrast between the white of the paper and the red of the blood staining it. Desperate for any 

clues leading out of this eerie town, you pick it up and smooth it out carefully as to not damage it 

further. It reads as follows: 888 paces north, 636 paces east, 770 paces west, 946 paces west.. no end in 

sight..";
r_text[4] = "You cant see anything, you dont hear anything, but a chill just shot down your spine and you 

cant shake this deep feeling of uneasiness.";
r_text[5] = "A strange smell like that of a rotting corpse hits your nose. You should turn back.";
r_text[6] = "You look and look and even shout out if anyone can hear you and find nothing, but you cant 

shake the feeling that youre being watched.";
r_text[7] = "You look and look and even shout out if anyone can hear you and find nothing, but you cant 

shake the feeling that youre being watched.";
r_text[8] = "You walk down a street of decrep old buildings that all seem uninhabited. No one is around, 

not even stray animals. For as far as you can see in every direction is nothing but more old ruined 

buildings.";
r_text[9] = "You walk down a street of decrep old buildings that all seem uninhabited. No one is around, 

not even stray animals. For as far as you can see in every direction is nothing but more old ruined 

buildings.";
r_text[10] = "You walk down a street of decrep old buildings that all seem uninhabited. No one is around, 

not even stray animals. For as far as you can see in every direction is nothing but more old ruined 

buildings.";
r_text[11] = "You happen upon a building with an open doorway. The building looks stable enough to 

explore so you walk up to the entrance. Near the doorway you find an old dusty sign with writing you cant 

quite read on it. After dusting the sign off, you find out this build used to be the town's library. You 

enter optimisitically thinking you'll find some clues on how to leave the acursed town, or what happened 

to the inhabitants. <p>Carefully you explore the internal perimeter of the library to make sure theres 

nothing inside waiting for you. Upon securing that there are no other living things in the library beside 

yourself, you switch to your next goal: finding information. Searching for hours and hours through 

hundreds of books taken randomly from just about every shelf you skim the contents of every book looking 

for some scrap of useful information. From what you can gather the town's name is Innsmouth and it used 

to be a thriving fishery and gold refinery but war and inbreeding dwindled the town's population to 

nearly nothing. <p>Esoteric cults moved into the desolate town with promise of economic recovery through 

prayer and converted most of the surviving population, though rumors were the conversions were mostly by 

force. Articles of disappearances were the only other useful bits of information that could be called 

recent but the last one was dated fifteen years ago. You slump down in your chair, sigh a great sigh, 

then stretch your legs and stand up to go find the nearest window. Its almost dark. You decide to spend 

the night in the library. During your final inspection of the place before going to sleep for anything 

lurking, you find a book that seemed wholly out of place, it looked like an ancient tome, extradanarily 

thick and fantasically decorated. The very look of it was sinister. <p>For a minute you debated whether 

you should look through it, toss it out of the building or find a whole other building to sleep in for 

the night. Ultimately you decide you came here for useful information and this is the only book in the 

whole library that looks promising. Without picking it up, you stand near enough to read the title.. The 

Necronomicon. Hesitantly, you pick the book up as if it were a venomous snake ready to strike at any 

moment. Carefully you lay it on a nearby table and proceed to open the front cover.<p> You spend the 

entire night pouring over the ancient tome until the light of day stings your over-strained dry eyes. The 

only way to maintain your own sanity after reading the contents of The Necronomicon you resign yourself 

to believing this was the Bible to the esoteric cults who took over Innsmouth and it is nothing more than 

religious fanatic gobbilty-gook. The world in which you and every other person on this earth and the 

world portrayed in The Necronomicon just CANT be the same one. You try and try to get some sleep but 

every time you close your eyes one of the frightful monsters depicted in the Necronomicon came to the 

front of your mind's eye. You decide it would be best to put away the tome and not touch it again, and 

focus on resting up so you may try venturing out tomorrow morning to find a way out of this increasingly 

freightening town.";
r_text[12] = "You feel like youve been walking for hours without finding anything useful, any people, 

animals, or ways out of the town.";
r_text[13] = "you find an abandoned general store, through the windows it looks like there may be some 

rations still inside. You try for the door but its baracaded by some fallen roof beams. After surveying 

the area for anything lurking and confirming that you are alone within normal earshot, you take a large 

chunk of fallen brick and break open an entrance through a large front window. The sound of the glass 

breaking was the first sound youve heard in incountable hours. Your heart pounds and youre sure SOMETHING 

lurking out there heard you and must be coming after you now. Youre first instinct is to hide. <p>You 

hide behind a counter and scope out your surrounding fervently listening for the slightest little sound. 

The sound of your own heart pounding makes it hard to hear anything else. Every time you think its ok to 

move, you realize your freightened state of mind can make five minutes feels like hours, again and again 

you stop yourself from moving. Hours pass by and you notice a distinct change in the sun's position from 

the shadows sprawled out on the floor. Finally you decide its safe to venture out in search of rations 

after one more survey of the inside of the store. Your efforts paid off in enough water to satisfy your 

thirst and some old canned goods easily opened with tools also found in the shop you gladly chanced and 

wolfed down. You decide to hold up in this store until youre fully recovered and resolved to venture out 

in the town again to find a way out.";
r_text[14] = "while trying to find a suitable shelter for the soon-coming night, you walk up to a 

building with an open doorway and peer inside. instantly a chill creeps down your spine. a glimpse of a 

dusty sign catches your gaze and you quickly dust it off to read it. It reads: The Esoteric Order of 

Dagon. This is one of the churches of the cult that took over the town and quite possibly caused the 

town's mass dissertion.<p> After that terrifying realization gave way to the ability to control your 

limbs again, you decide to run and find a different shelter as far away from this building as you can. ";
r_text[15] = "while walking around the town you notice most of the land appears to be flat and the 

numerous old delatidated buildings made it very hard to see much more than a few hundred feet down a 

single street at a time. All of a sudden you spot the first elevation youve see since youve arrived. You 

race for it to try and gain a vantage point of any kind to figure out which direction to go. The 

elevation turns out to be less than 10 feet high and gives almost no vantage point as your view is still 

obstructed by all of the ancient tottering buildings. You need need to climb ontop of a roof to gain any 

vantage. ";
r_text[16] = "during your time exploring the town you have noticed most of the roads have been unmarked 

or had their street signs torn down with no remnant of the name left to be read. That fact is what made 

this street before you stand out from all the other identical streets youve been walking up and down 

endlessly. An intact street sign that read Main street. What luck! It doesnt matter which direction you 

follow the street, Main should always lead to other streets that will allow you to LEAVE the town! <p>You 

follow Main street for as far as your legs can take you day in and day out, only stopping during the 

night to take shelter in nearby abandoned buildings, and looking for food and water. Weeks passed by and 

still not a single change in the scenery could be found, no people, no animals, everything in bitter 

unyielding silence. There seems to be no forseeable end to this street.";
r_text[17] = "the sun is high in the sky and heading toward dusk. it happens much quicker than it should 

and light becomes scarce in this town with no electricity after the sun starts to come back down. This is 

about the time I start looking for a shelter to stay the night in, preferably something with drinkable 

water inside as the search for food was given up long ago. After trying three other houses on this street 

I find one with a door I can pry open. Upon entering the house Im overcome with the stench of mold and 

mildew, which mean there must be water somewhere. I decide to investigate. <p>Very silently I roam around 

the house with nothing but a few sun spots to light my way. Its almost impossible to distinguish what 

each room's original purpose was, there was no discernable kitchen or bathroom to be made out in such 

little light without blindly groping in the dark to maybe find something that resembles a sink, toilet, 

tub or exposed pipes, which was not something I was quite ignorant enough to do. Upon entering the next 

room I hear something squish under my foot and feel a dampness. After walking a few more steps I discover 

the entire floor is covered in less than an inch of water. I would imagine its rain water leaked through 

the same holes in the walls and roof the sun spots are coming from, however, Ive been in this town for a 

while now and Ive not once seen it rain. <p>I kneel down and cup my hands to scoop up some water. First I 

feel the texture, is it slimy, sludgy, or sooty? Next I smell it, is it tainted or fresh rainwater? It 

felt stagnant, not dirty but not necessarily fresh. It had been here a while for certain. The smell was 

what threw me for a loop, it was distinctively salty, like ocean water. <p> Nonetheless, I couldnt drink 

it. 
I was however, curious as to how salty ocean water got into this house. But the quickly fading sunlight 

was not enough to give a thurough investigation. On my way toward what I thought was the exit, I found a 

staircase leading up I had not found earlier. The light seemed the be stronger upstairs, so I thought a 

few minutes of sunlight would be worth a vantage point of the town from a second story window, and maybe 

perhaps an easy-enough climb to a roof. <p>The stairs seemed sturdy enough but they creaked rather loudly 

under my feet. I unconsciously held my breath as I walked up the stairs and exhaled when I could actually 

see the second floor of the house, it wasnt brightly lit by any means but enough sun poured in from old 

windows and holes in the roof to light the second floor well enough for it to be easily explored. The 

smell of mildrew was stronger up here as well and I soon found the bottom of my shoes to be soaked. 

Everything up here was wet, like a firehose had been taken to it. I instinctively head toward the most 

brightly lit room, hoping for an open window. Peering in the doorway I find my open window! 

<p>Unfortunately, the room is flooded with several inches of water and broken household objects litterly 

the floor, poking up from the water like bones from a hastily-dug grave. I decide to check the other 

rooms first. The second room I try has a closed door and it wont budge, it seems to be baracaded from the 

other side. The next room is open but theres a large hole in the middle of the floor and it doesnt seem 

to be stable enough to walk across to get to the nearest window. The first room is the best option. 

-------------------------------------- ";
r_text[18] = "Nestled down in my shelter for the night, having made sure all was quiet and vacant before 

attempting to fall asleep. Abruptly, in the dead of the night Im awakened by the croaking of frogs 

outside. Up until this very moment I hadnt heard or seen so much as a living insect, let alone a frog. 

This disturbed me greatly.";
r_text[19] = "saw a fishfrog creature";
r_text[20] = "saw a cultist group";
r_text[21] = "saw cthulhu";
r_text[22] = "hear noises";
r_text[23] = "chased by a cultist";
r_text[24] = "find cultist materials";
r_text[25] = "spot cultists or fishfrogs on devils reef";
r_text[26] = "chased by fishfrogs";
r_text[27] = "found an underground tunnel";
r_text[28] = "cthulhu dreams";
r_text[29] = "I hear strange spectral piping";
r_text[30] = "when i saw the people, or what i thought were people, i instantly shouted out to them to 

get their attention. i wish i hadnt done that.";
r_text[31] = "a night of despair";
r_text[32] = "i thought it was a dream but it wasnt, how did I get here?";
r_text[33] = "going inside a church to investigate";
r_text[34] = "event 34";
r_text[35] = "event 35";    
r_text[36] = "event 36";
r_text[37] = "event 37";
r_text[38] = "event 38";
r_text[39] = "event 39";
r_text[40] = "event 40";
r_text[41] = "event 41";
r_text[42] = "event 42";
r_text[43] = "event 43";
r_text[44] = "event 44";
r_text[45] = "event 45";
r_text[46] = "event 46";
r_text[47] = "event 47";
r_text[48] = "event 48";
r_text[49] = "event 49";
r_text[50] = "event 50";

var i = Math.floor(51*Math.random())
document.write( r_text[i] );
```